# React Select with OpenAI API Integration - Items Not Displaying and Slow Response

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-select

I am working on a project where I'm using React Select to display options fetched from an API with OpenAI integration. However, I'm encountering two issues:

Items not displaying: Even though I'm certain there is data in the list retrieved from the API, the options are not showing up in the React Select component.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKsCd.png

Slow response: When I select one of the blanked options, there is a significant delay before it is displayed.

````
import useSWR from "swr";
import Select from "react-select";


const fetchModels = () => fetch('/api/getEngines').then(res => res.json());

function ModelSelection() {
    const {data: models, isLoading } = useSWR ("models", fetchModels);
    const { data: model, mutate: setModel } = useSWR('model', {
        fallbackData: 'Select you model',
    });

    if (models && models.modelOptions) {
      console.log("Available Options:", models.modelOptions);
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <Select className="mt-2"
        options={models?.modelOptions}
        defaultValue={model}
        placeholder={model}
        isSearchable
        isLoading={isLoading}
        menuPosition='fixed'
        classNames={{
            control: (state) => "bg-black border-[#434654]"
        }}
        onChange={(e) => setModel(e.value)}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ModelSelection```
````